# Spark write to CSV: commas in string cols being taken as separators

Tags: python, database, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using pySpark to write some CSVs.
The problem I'm having can be seen in the screenshot below: When my string fields have commas, it looks like that (this can be seen perfectly in excel) the CSV/the Data is taking the comma in the string as a lineseparator, and thanks to that it's messing up with the structure of my data.
I think this has something to do with quotes or escape, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Would appreciate your help, this seems pretty sensitive but I've spent many hours already. These commas in my string columns should be escaped so they won't count as lineseparators, as it's happening right now... I've seen other similar questions on stackoverflow but the solution wasn't clear.

[image: See problem in the data]

Here's my code that writes the csvs:

```
def write_to_csv(df, path, compression):
    print("log: starting to write the csvs, this might take some time")
    df.write.csv(path = path ,sep=",", header=True, lineSep="\n", escape='"', nullValue=None, compression=compression)
    print("log: finished writing csvs")
```

Comment: You might want to check the actual created csv-file instead of opening it wiht something like excel. The program you are opening /displaying it with, might not correctly work with quoted columnvalues giving the above impression whereas - if it correctly used quoted lines - it would be ok. I've no experience in pyspark but your df.write.csv Method has different params from what pandas regularily uses in df.to_csv()  but according to the API you are doing good: [pysparks df.write.csv](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv.html)

Comment: How are the raw lines in your raw csv-file looking if opened in a textediter like notepad++ ? Are the columnvalues quoted inside "...."? In that case your excel viewer is bad.

Comment: indeed it was just the csv showing the file bad, the escape="'" was also necessary, everything is good thanks for the help!